# Role-based accesses control in a system using c#

Tags: c#, database-design, usertype

I'm creating a restaurant management system, I want to **enable or disable some buttons** according to the user type.

For example, if the user have `admin` type account then `Edit salary` button is enabled; if the user does not have `admin` rights then the button should be disabled.

I created two tables using sql. First one is `USER` and it have(`Username`, `Password` and `UserTypeID` columns), and the other table has(`UserTypeID` and `Usertype`).

How can I do this? Is there any other way to do?

Comment: i just post this to get an idea how to do this because am a beginner if u don't need to help it's OK. thank you!   i just post only to get a idea not to have the hole bunch of code thank you bro

Comment: Is this web-based or a desktop app?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Java and Spring take a look at Spring Security.  Their DSL features and tag libraries should be able to help